# ubuntuでインストールに失敗することが多くなりました。

Tags: linux, ubuntu

javaのインストールで初めて下のようなエラーが出ていたのですが、その時は、別のブラウザで対応すれば問題なく利用できたので放置しましたが、今日になってインストールをじっこうした結果、パッケージの依存関係に異常があるようで何度かエラーが出ました。その、通知のものは消えてしまったので以下の情報しか提出することができません。

> /var/lib/dpkg/info/jre1.8.0-60.postinst: 行 641:
>   /usr/sbin/alternatives: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません dpkg: error processing
>   package jre1.8.0-60 (--configure):  サブプロセス インストール済みの post-installation
>   スクリプト はエラー終了ステータス 127 を返しました 処理中にエラーが発生しました:  jre1.8.0-60 E:
>   Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

実行したコマンドは、以下でちょっとお絵描きをしようかなと。。；

```
$ sudo apt-get install krita
```

`Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`で検索するといくつか方法が出てくるので以下を試したのですが

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f krita
```

うまく行きません。
自分のLinuxが今どういった状態なのか全く理解できていないのですが、何かしらの解決策はありませんか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そのJava（JRE）はどのようにインストールした物ですか？ （apt-getでインストールした場合はパッケージ名が知りたいです）
`/usr/sbin/alternatives` というのは今の Ubuntu に無いので（覚えてないですが、昔は有ったのかも）、今のUbuntu向けでないパッケージをインストールしているのかも知れません。

`/usr/sbin/alternatives` というのが、`update-alternatives` と互換性が有るコマンドならば、下記のようにリンクしておけば動くでしょう。

```
# !確認していません!
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/update-alternatives /usr/sbin/alternatives
```

いずれにしろ、別のシステムの JRE が混じっているならば、削除しておく事をお勧めします。